# geoext3 extjs 6 editing grid

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geoext, ext-js

I am building a map web app using geoext-3 and extjs-6. I managed to create a editor grid to edit the attributes of features I have in Geoserver. However when I click on update button the value did not changed and returned back to the previous value.

Is there any common mistake I made and caused this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using OpenLayers 3.

You could use WFS-T to request to Geoserver to change data as described in a blog post titled [WFS-T with OpenLayers 3.16](https://medium.com/@goldrydigital/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-16-6fb6a820ac58):

Comment: can we use store.sync() method to update the attributes that are modified

Comment: You still need to write customized WFS-T functions in store.sync(). geoext-3 and extjs-6 not provide functions to deal with geoserver at this moment.